# errors in conversion decimal,binary,octal,hex

Tags: java, binary, hex, decimal, octal

I have a code I am working on and I want to build a converter for bin, octal, hex and decimal. I have a frame where there is a text space where you can input into either of those options. Depending on where you enter your input, the program will convert it to the other forms. My problem is that it can convert the decimal to the other forms but not vice versa? I'm confused because I think the logical flow is there, any help would be greatly appreciated by this coder.

```
import javax.swing.*; //library used for the layout
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener{  

JLabel l1 = new JLabel("   Decimal   ");
JLabel l2 = new JLabel("    Binary   ");
JLabel l3 = new JLabel("    Octal    "); 
JLabel l4 = new JLabel(" Hexadecimal ");
JTextField f1 = new JTextField(20);
JTextField f2 = new JTextField(20);
JTextField f3 = new JTextField(20);
JTextField f4 = new JTextField(20);
JButton b1 = new JButton("Calculate");

public Gui() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //row x column

    add(l1);
    add(f1);
    add(l2);
    add(f2);        
    add(l3);
    add(f3);
    add(l4);
    add(f4);
    add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==this.b1){
        if(this.f1.getText()!="")
        {
            String text1 = this.f1.getText();//get the text and store it in a string named text1
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text1); // get the integer value of the variable text1

            String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(num1); //convert the variable num1 to binary
            this.f2.setText(binary);

            String octal = Integer.toOctalString(num1); //convert the variable num1 to binary
            this.f3.setText(octal);

            String hexadecimal = Integer.toHexString(num1); //convert the variable num1 to binary
            this.f4.setText(hexadecimal);       
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: here is a gui code if you want to test it for yourselves                      import javax.swing.*;


public class Control {

 public static void main(String[] args){

 Gui obj = new Gui();
 obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 obj.setSize(300 ,450); //width x length
 obj.setTitle("Number Converter"); //title
 obj.setVisible(true);
    
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

This line expects the string to be in decimal.

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text1);
```

You need a way for the user to specify what format the text is in if it is not always going to be decimal.

You can parse binary, octal and hex using the radix argument.

Parse binary:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text,2);
```

Parse octal:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text,8);
```

Parse hex:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text,16);
```

To specify which to use you could either have multiple buttons or add an ActionListener to each JTextField. With each one reading the text from that field and setting the other values.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused because I think the logical flow is there,

No, This logic that you have, looks at the `f1` field and convert that decimal value to other formats.

> Depending on where you enter your input, the program will convert it
>   to the other forms.

I guess what you want to achieve is have any form of value in respective form and convert that into other formats when the user press the Calculate Button.

So, you will decide how you want to do this,

1. weather you want to remove the calculate button and update the fields listening to the changes on each JTextField.
2. Keep the Calculate button and assume that last updated JTextField is the one that you use to convert to other formats.

In either case,

you will have to listen to the changes of the JTextField. using,

```
 // Listen for changes in the text f1
     f1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
      }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
      }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        update();
      }

      public void update() {
         // update a local variable to keep the last updated JTextFeild 
         // or update to the rest of the formats on the fly.
         // You can update/ show errors of the input values 

         //Scenario 1,

         int decimal = Integer.parseInt(f1.getText());
         String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal); //convert the variable num1 to binary
         this.f2.setText(binary);

         String octal = Integer.toOctalString(decimal); //convert the variable num1 to binary
         this.f3.setText(octal);

         String hexadecimal = Integer.toHexString(decimal); //convert the variable num1 to binary
         this.f4.setText(hexadecimal);  
      }
    });
```